# Which jars are required for embedded Neo4j?

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

I'm looking for an updated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752298/which-jars-exactly-are-needed-to-embed-neo4j).  Previously, a minimal Neo4j "Hello World" app required two jars.  Now it apparently requires some other jars, but I don't know which ones.

If I include neo4j-kernel-2.1.2 and geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1 as suggested in that other question, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.collection.primitive.PrimitiveLongIterator
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

If I add neo4j-primitive-collections-2.1.2, I then get an error with this root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No schema index provider org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider found.
```

Answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589767/issues-in-connecting-to-neo4j-from-linux) suggest I need neo4j-lucene-index.  When I add that jar, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Finally, when I add lucene-core, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

What do I need to add to get past that?

Comment: You linked to another post which seems to partially answer your question, you have to include the lucene jar. I'm not sure exactly which one that is, but you might be able to look at the neo4j pom.xml of maven to get an idea of what is included. Otherwise if you download the neo4j installation and your your classpath at the directory under lib it should be all inclusive of what you need to perform the operations for everything neo4j has to offer.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to use Neo4j at all if I need 29 MB of jars to embed it into my 3 MB application.  I'm looking for the minimal "Hello World" dependencies.

Comment: To do search indexing you need at least the lucene JAR's. I only recommended all those as a way of getting your example working.

Comment: I wasn't interested in indexing, but your mention of it led me to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found the minimal set of dependencies for Neo4j 2.x.  I was originally trying to use `lucene-core-4.9.0`, but the `org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable` interface was removed from that library sometime after version 3.6.2.  The minimal set of jars is thus:

```
neo4j-kernel (2.1.2)
neo4j-primitive-collections (2.1.2)
neo4j-lucene-index (2.1.2)
lucene-core (3.6.2)
jta (1.1)
```

These weigh in at about 4.5 MB, which is larger than I'd like, but I guess I can live with it.  I've also been told that `neo4j-lucene-index` (which is what requires `lucene-core`) is not strictly required.  Like `jta`, it's actually only one possible implementation of a required interface.  But I don't know of any other implementation.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer correctly mention the most easy way is use a build tool featuring a dependency manager. Most widely these days used are Maven and Gradle. Both use Maven Central repository by default to pull dependencies and transitive dependencies.

Depending whether your embedded application uses cypher or not you should add the following dependencies your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-lucene-index</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or (when cypher is used):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Both of them transitively include all necessary libraries.

Comment: I'm not using Maven on this project.

Looking at the pom for neo4j-kernel isn't helpful.  It does not appear to require lucene, yet lucene is clearly required.

Comment: that's why I'm refering to `neo4j-lucene-index` which depends (among other) to `neo4j-kernel` ;-)

Comment: That's backward, though.  The pom for `neo4j-kernel` should list the dependency on `neo4j-lucene-index`.

Comment: Is there some alternative to Lucene included in Neo4j itself?  I keep finding hints that there is, but no information about how to use it.

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand the rationale of your question. Most java devs out there use a build system with dependency management for a good reason. If you decide otherwise you have to manage your dependencies on your own.

Comment: I will use a build system when I use Neo4j in a real project, but right now I just want to run a "Hello, World". I have no problem managing the dependencies on my own, but I need to know **what they are**.  (And in the case of indexing, what the options are.)  The docs are very vague, referring to an archive of dozens of jars totalling 29 MB and saying, "use these."

Comment: The best way I know of to figure out the whole tree of dependencies is to let Maven pull in the small number of top-level dependencies, and then examine all the lower-level dependencies that have been pulled in with them.  Trying to trace them by hand is not really time-well-spent.